# Using a common be verb for adjective and noun

Tags: grammar, be

Are the following sentences grammatically correct?

> **A**: He is nice and a grocer.
>
> **B**: He is nice and is a grocer.

Comment: The first one is much worse, but neither are idiomatic. Why would you want to connect the two statements *"He is nice"* and *"He is a grocer"* with *"**and**"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both "correct" in the sense there's nothing much ungrammatical there.

However, we do not propagate POSs and clauses forward across disparate things like a person's disposition (*nice*) and occupation (*grocer*). The overall semantic coherence is effected.

Not just the *is* but also the *He* needs to be provided again.

> He is nice and he is a grocer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a word for the first example, He is nice and a grocer. It is called *zeugma,* meaning yoking, an allusion, I suppose, to the biblical injunction not to yoke an ox with an ass. The device can be used to literary effect: "Eggs and promises are easily broken." The absurdity of joining the statements of this fellow's disposition and his profession is not much helped by making two clauses by inserting a second "he is" unless you want to suggest it is unusual for a grocer to be nice.

Comment: It still doesn't look like a zeugma to me at all, though.